# How can I modify anonymous element attributes in XUL?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, xul, xbl

I'm using the [autocomplete textbox element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XUL/Textbox_%28Toolkit_autocomplete%29) in a Firefox extension, and I have the `showcommentcolumn` attribute set to true. As a result, two columns appear in the autocomplete output results. Unfortunately, the width of the second column is too wide. This is a direct result of these tree columns both having the attribute `flex="1"` set.

I should mention that the setter method for the `showCommentColumn` property down in the *autocomplete-result-popup* binding seems to do what I want: ([see its source here](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-release/source/toolkit/content/widgets/autocomplete.xml#618)). When the property is set, the column should have its `flex` attribute set to 2. In my case, however, this doesn't seem to happen. The XBL binding on my `textbox` control is pointing to the right thing, but that code doesn't seem to alter things.

Is there a simple way I can alter the `flex` attribute for the first column to be `flex="2"`? Unfortunately, these are anonymous content nodes, and I'm not sure how best to alter them (or if it's even possible). I'd rather not roll my own autocomplete search box to fix this one nit. Is there an easy way to alter the attributes of an anonymous node?

Comment: See my answer to very similar querstion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23261556/getelementbyid-a-xbl-bound-xul-element/23441316#23441316